# JQuery code to perform the following task using advanced selectors. PS : cihldren() not workin

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

How can we display only first 2 list items and also, how to make background color of children under

tag to GREEN.
ONLY JQUERY TO BE USED

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Advanced Selectors</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="intro">jQuery is a lightweight, "write less, do more" JavaScript library.
        <h6>The purpose of jQuery is to make it much easier to use
             JavaScript on your website</h6>
    </p>
    <ol>
        <li>HTML/DOM manipulation</li>
        <li>CSS manipulation</li>
        <li>Effects and animations</li>
        <li>AJAX</li>
    </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

My JQuery Code is not working

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{
   //Code to make children of P to green 
   $("p").children().css('background-color:green');
   //Code to display only first 2 items of list

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to mention why your code isn't working is because first you can't have a h6-tag inside a p-tag.

Secondly you wrote:

```
$("p").children().css('background-color:green');
```

Better that you iterate through each of the children like this (note that you wrote the values inside the css()-function wrong):

```
$("#intro").children().each(function(){
  $(this).css("background-color", "green");
});
```

When it comes to only showing two list items you can do it this way:

```
$("ol").children().each(function() {
index = $(this).index();
if (index > 1) {
  $(this).hide();
}
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/boe2sdyk/

Comment: hey, thanks for the quick help. Appreciate it. The list is hidden. But the code for background is still not working. It works for the DIV tag, but not for the <p> tag

Comment: @ROHITKF No problem. That's because you can't have an h6 tag inside a p-tag.

Comment: ohh ok. No wonder why it wasn't working. Thanks a lot for your help